# Updated NPM now Gulp doesn't work within Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, npm, gulp

As the title says, I recently updated NPM and now Gulp is no longer a command in my Git Bash terminal on Windows 10.

I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, editing path variables and have had no luck. Running this command to install I get the following:

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli

C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\gulp -> C:\Program 
Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local
`-- gulp-cli@1.3.0
```

But then running this it seems it thinks it's in a different directory:

```
$ where gulp

C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp.cmd
```

I've also tried doing this in the Windows command line and it works. I'm guessing my Git Bash is looking for it in the wrong place? Just unsure as how to rectify.

Any help would be muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seems the update added a prefix path above all the default values in my NPM config file telling it to install into the Git folder.

Taking this out and resetting to the default values fixed it.